# How to list files in a remote server

Tags: http, go, https

I implemented a function to download files from a remote server.

```
func runDownload(fileName string) error {
    url := constants.REGISTRY_URL + "/" + constants.REGISTRY_ORGANIZATION + "/" + fileName + "/2.0.0-m1"
    if cellImage == "" {
        return fmt.Errorf("no fileName specified")
    }

    dir, err := filepath.Abs(filepath.Dir(os.Args[0]))
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error in getting current directory location: " + err.Error())
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    response, downloadError := util.DownloadFile(dir+"/"+fileName, url)

    if downloadError != nil {
        fmt.Printf("\x1b[31;1m Error occurred while pulling the cell image: \x1b[0m %v \n", downloadError)
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    if response.StatusCode == 200 {
        fmt.Printf("\r\033[32m Successfully pulled fileName \033[m %s \n", util.Bold(fileName))
    }
    if response.StatusCode == 404 {
        fmt.Printf("\x1b[31;1m Error occurred while running file:\x1b[0m %v not found in registry\n", cellImage)
    }
    return nil
}
```

This calls a utility function and downloads a file.

```
func DownloadFile(filepath string, url string) (*http.Response, error) {
    transport := &http.Transport{
        TLSClientConfig: &tls.Config{InsecureSkipVerify: true},
    }
    client := &http.Client{Transport: transport}

    resp, err := client.Get(url)
    if err != nil {
        return resp, err
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    if resp.StatusCode == 200 {
        out, err := os.Create(filepath)
        if err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }
        defer out.Close()
        _, err = io.Copy(out, resp.Body)
        if err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }
    }
    return resp, nil
}
```

This works fine and i am able to download a file. Now I want to list the details of the files uploaded. (Name, size)

Comment: ReadDir() on the filepath.Dir(os.Args[0]), convert to json and attach it to the body of the response

Comment: Don't create a new transport for every request: "By default, Transport caches connections for future re-use. [...] Transports should be reused instead of created as needed." https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Transport

Comment: to execute code on a remote server lookup ssh ... for example ... `ssh -A -n -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o BatchMode=yes ${remote_user}@${remote_host}  'ls -la /tmp/'`   ... conveniently golang has a ssh library see https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/crypto/ssh